# clearing cookies through javascript in webview- iphone

Tags: javascript, iphone, cookies, logout

Im doing an iphone application where i login using OAuth apis of the website for the login process and the status in the uiwebview remains as logged in all the time. I thought clearing the cookies in the uiwebview would help me logout. I want a logout option per say to the app. I have done this to clear all the cookies in uiwebview.

1) i have created a script.js and added it to the project which has the following code

```
function deleteAllCookies() {
    var cookies = document.cookie.split(";");

    for (var i = 0; i < cookies.length; i++) {
       var cookie = cookies[i];
       var eqPos = cookie.indexOf("=");
       var name = eqPos > -1 ? cookie.substr(0, eqPos) : cookie;
       document.cookie = name + "=;expires=Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:00 GMT";
    }
}
```

2) i have added this code in one of the view controller which has a logout button. As soon as the botton is clicked, this code is executed

```
- (void)injectJavascript:(NSString *)resource {
NSString *jsPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:resource ofType:@"js"];
NSString *js = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:jsPath encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:NULL];

[webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:js];
}


-(void)logoutFromApp
{    
[self injectJavascript:@"script"];
}
```

First of all im not even sure that this code is working. How will i know if it has cleared all the cookies.? Meaning, how will i be notified that it has succeeded clearing or not?

Is what im opting to do is the best way of doing this or are there any other methods to give a logout option?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK i solved the issue..

```
#import <Foundation/NSHTTPCookie.h>


NSHTTPCookie *aCookie;
for (aCookie in [[NSHTTPCookieStorage sharedHTTPCookieStorage] cookies]) 
{
    [[NSHTTPCookieStorage sharedHTTPCookieStorage] deleteCookie:aCookie];
}
```

this deletes all the cookies in the uiwebview. Works great.

Comment: i have just 6 month exp. hope u have nice exp... really appreciate ur work

Comment: oh ok... all the best for the rest

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/46845/discussion-between-sharanya-k-m-and-immi)

Comment: So is there a way to clear cookies using java script?